# Upload files first and fill remaining data while file is uploaded in form

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, frontend

This may be very basic but I have this situation:

I want to upload multiple files on server and once the file is submitted; I want to show the user a progress bar for file being uploaded and during that time user can fill remaining data in the form.

There is one solution where I can create a temporary folder where files uploaded will be stored before the whole information is filled.

Is there any other solution than this?

Comment: There are many possible solutions. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to start file upload in the beginning of form filling process to save time and then user can continue filling remaining text information in form fields. I hope I am addressing your query.

Comment: What do you think of this tutorial? https://serversideup.net/drag-and-drop-file-uploads-with-vuejs-and-axios/

Comment: I have seen this tutorial. I will post one example.